# How to list installed versions of the same program

Tags: bash

I have a program called PyMOL installed multiple times on my machine. One was installed by MacPorts, one was installed through the developers distribution channel and so on. One is in /opt/local/bin, the other is in /i/have/no/clue.

I know I can use "which pymol" to see, where the one that is executed is located, but how can I get the location of the other ones with the same name?

Answer (score 3):

You have the right command and just need to set the proper option:

`which -a pymol` will show all instances of the executable `pymol` located within your `PATH`.

For example, on my laptop I have `git` installed in two places:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

provides what will be run when I use the command `git`.

```
$ which -a git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
```

provides every instance of the executable in my `PATH`.

Comment: This really is the best answer. The top result in `which -a foo` will tell you the default.

Comment: OK, but how about instances not in $PATH? I'm actually after the instances I don't know about, and which therefore I have not added to $PATH.

Answer (score 2):

`whereis pymol` should show you all matches that are in your executable path.

Comment: Btw it works also on other unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "find" or "locate" and then run the results through "grep".

This will give you more than the results of "which" or "whereis" which will only show things on $PATH.

"locate" is faster, but uses an index which isn't always up-to-date.

"find" is slower, doing a recursive search of everything, but it produces all results -- not just the results that have been indexed like "locate" does.

Comment: I always have trouble correctly using "find". Can you provide an example of how you would use "find" here?

Comment: I have trouble using the "find" command too.  That's why I like a GUI interface such as what is in the "Easy Find" app: http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html

Comment: I did recommend the "find" command, so  I'll post some examples.

Answer (score 0):

At least according to its man page, `whereis` doesn't search in `$PATH` but in the result of `sysctl user.cs_path` (which doesn't contain any additional directories added by the user's profile). To search for the command based on the actual `$PATH` you could use a shell function like

```
function whereis() {
    for p in ${PATH//:/ }; do
        [[ -x "$p/$1" ]] && echo "$p"
    done
}
```

or (for your specific case) run

```
for p in ${PATH//:/ }; do [[ -x "$p"/pymol ]] && echo "$p" ; done
```

---

PS: The space character near the end of`${PATH...}`is essential for this to work.